# glLight in fragment shader (screen pos)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I would like to create a fragment shader that renders a white circle at the position of the glLightSource. But somehow I have a hard time figuring out how to convert the glLight position in screen coordinates...

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: You cannot do it in the fragment shader anyway, because the fragment shader cannot decide where to render, it gets a fragment and sets its attributes, without generating new fragments or changing the fragment's position. You can only set the vertex position to the light position inside the vertex shader and there it is no problem to compute it, since you just have to transform it by the view and projection matrices. But you cannot generate a new vertex inside the vertex shader either, for this you need the geometry shader.

Comment: I have a fragment shader rendering a full screen quad in a postpro setup. I don't need new vertexes, i just want to paint the fragments around the position of gl_LightSource.position with some particular color...

Answer (score 1):

You have to multiply the `gl_LightSource.position` with the `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` to get the screen coordinates (for OpenGL 2.x—with OGL 3.x+ you of course have to use a uniform for your matrix). However, the problem is that you still have to find the correct pixel in your fullscreen quad - that is, you have to compute this for each fragment and then test if the current fragment position is the same as your light's screen space position.

I would therefore strongly suggest to use a vertex with the coordinates of the light and draw it as suggested by Christian Rau.

Comment: Yes, this is very close, thanks. Actually it was mulitplying with the **inverse** `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`.